# Managing server files in django

Tags: python, django

I see various bits of information in the docs, but I can't seem to form the complete picture.

I wish to hold various text, audio and video files on the server. At the moment I'm not planning to add user upload support but it would be nice to expand to that in the future.

I just don't understand where to start and what to do. Where do I save those files on the server? What is the best way for django to interact with those files?

I hope that you can help me with the confusion :)

Comment: I'd suggest saving the files with the rest of your root files, most likely in a folder that's locked down from directory listings ect. The best way for django to interact with the files is a bit of a tricky question, do you mean just retrieve the files?

Comment: First of all, what do you mean by root files? I have to say I have barely used django so I don't really know how to handle static files. Secondly, I want to simply get the contents of the files. Things like streaming the audio or video I will handle another time.

Comment: Audio and video files can be clearly classified as media. In your `settings.py` you can specify the values for `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT`. Since your new to Django I'd suggest you to stick with the default values and put all these files in the directory `media`.

Comment: Okay, so I put everything under /app/media. But how to I access these files in the code? Do I simply use file objects like regular python or is there a more 'django-esque' way?

Comment: In the templates you can access this files with `{{ MEDIA_URL }}path/to/media }}`. In your model classes you would define the exact path where the files should be uploaded. The `FileField` has an option `upload_to`. There you define the part behind `MEDIA_URL` (by default `media`). Hope it helps, for more details you have to go through the documentation.